# Numbers not on the same line

Tags: css

I've added a contact bar at the top but for some reason the numbers aren't on the same line.

http://puu.sh/kY9xG/6aed0786fc.png

css

```
.top_bar .tob_bar_right_col p {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 14px 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: That's would possibly be the font that makes the numbers vertically align like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the font that you are using.

Some fonts uses the old way of placing the digits ([text figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures)), with ascenders and descenders. The new way of placing the digits (lining figures) treats them similar to capital letters.

To get the new way of placing the digits you need a font that uses that form, for example Arial.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct only.It's coming due to the default font you used. Change the font type like below

```
.top_bar .tob_bar_right_col p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 14px 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the `font-family` you are using. Some of them will make the numbers look weird. Just change you're `font-family` for that text and it should work.

Example:

```
.top_bar .tob_bar_right_col p {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a custom font, which appears different than other fonts.

You can check it e.g. by typing the same text in Gimp or Photoshop with the same font. It should output the same result.

Make sure, you're using the desired `font-family`.